# How do I go to the next tab onClick in a Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

- So basically I have two tabs in a `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` to store two fragments in a tab view.
- Thing is, I am using a card view in a `recycler view` and the card view has like a Like Button. Basically, when the user clicks the button, it should appear on the next tab - but it doesn't. It is only when the user comes out of the entire page and goes back onto it and selects that tab does the selected card view is displayed.
  I checked my database and it is doing what it should be, but it is the `recycler view` that doesn't update.

**This is my code for liking the contents in a card view**

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MSG: ";
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Context context;
    public View root;


    public int[] tabsUnselected = {
            R.drawable.unselected_notification,
            R.drawable.unselected_chat,
            R.drawable.unselected_issue,
            R.drawable.unselected_verified
    };

    public int[] tabSelected = {
            R.drawable.selected_notification,
            R.drawable.selected_chat,
            R.drawable.selected_issue,
            R.drawable.selected_verified
    };



    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        context = container.getContext();
        setupTabs(root);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabSelected[0]);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int position = tab.getPosition();

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabSelected[0]);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabSelected[1]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabSelected[2]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabSelected[3]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int position = tab.getPosition();
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabsUnselected[0]);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabsUnselected[1]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabsUnselected[2]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabsUnselected[3]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabsUnselected[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabsUnselected[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabsUnselected[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabsUnselected[3]);
    }

    public void setupTabs(View view) {
        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Notification(), "Notification");
        adapter.addFragment(new Conversation(), "Conversation");
        adapter.addFragment(new Issues(), "Issues");
        adapter.addFragment(new Pinned(), "Pinned");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void experiment() {

    }
```

> - So when first opened the tab works fine and recycler view is populated, but when a view is a click I want to go to another tab,
>     like the next tab.

**My pager adapter:**

```
    public class NotificationFeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationFeedAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<NotificationFeed> notificationFeedList;
    public Context context;


    public NotificationFeedAdapter(List<NotificationFeed> notificationFeedList) {
        this.notificationFeedList = notificationFeedList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notification_single_item, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();

        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final String list = notificationFeedList.get(position).NotificationFeedID;
        String body = notificationFeedList.get(position).getBody();
        String userHandle = notificationFeedList.get(position).getUserHandle();
        holder.descView.setText(body);
        holder.userName.setText(userHandle);
        holder.id = list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notificationFeedList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private View mView;
        private TextView descView;
        private TextView userName;
        private String id;
        private String TAG = "MSG: ";
        private TextView mMore;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            descView = mView.findViewById(R.id.body);
            userName = mView.findViewById(R.id.user);
            mMore = mView.findViewById(R.id.more);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Navigate to tab
        }
    }
    }
```

What will I put in the `onclick` event to get it going to the next tab.

Comment: You will not see any change because in viewpager ,2 fargments starts at the same time. As the other fragment is already in onResume state the changes are not shown until you restart the fragment. You can use a mutable live data to observe the changes in the next fragment.

Comment: how do I solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create `listener` containing parameter with desired tab to navigate, pass it to adapter, from `Adapter` pass it to `ViewHolder` and listen clicks in `HomeFragment` where you have `ViewPager` and navigate to whatever tab you want using

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNo)
```